# Does the SQL AG based corruption resolution work for a enterprise edition read scale AG and for basic AG?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019, corruption

SQL provides 2 kinds of AG architecture.

1. Basic AG (when either of the server has standard SQL edition)
2. Enterprise edition AG for HA
3. Enterprise edition AG for read scale (this doesn't require WSFC)

I am reading the SQL AG has a concept of automatic page repair upon corruption detection.

1. Does the SQL AG based corruption resolution work for a non HA AG (that is - read scale AG [which is AG without the WSFC])?
2. Does this work only with enterprise edition or also with standard edition (Basic AG)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL provides 2 kinds of AG architecture.

I wouldn't call those architectures, I know this wasn't your question, but it needed to be pointed out.

> Does the SQL AG based corruption resolution work for a non HA AG (that is - read scale AG [which is AG without the WSFC])?

Yes.

> Does this work only with enterprise edition or also with standard edition (Basic AG)?

All editions.